# Fill a column with values based on a search

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 columns

- name
- age

On another sheet, I want to create a column that lists all the names whose ages are over 30.

Is there a function that allows me to do this?

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question may be closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Try `QUERY`    ⠀‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Try `=FILTER(A2:A,B2:B>=30)`.

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr - this worked. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(A:A; B:B>=30)
```

or:

```
=QUERY(A:B; "select A where B >= 30"; )
```